# How does `HFix` work in Haskell's multirec package?

Tags: haskell, types, generic-programming, multirec

I understand the regular fixed-point type combinator and I think I understand the higher-order fixed-n type combinators, but `HFix` eludes me. Could you give an example of a set of data-types and their (manually derived) fixed points that you can apply `HFix` to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural reference is the paper [Generic programming with fixed points for mutually recursive datatypes](http://people.cs.uu.nl/andres/Rec/MutualRec.pdf)
 where the [multirec package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multirec) is explained.

`HFix` is a fixpoint type combinator for mutually recursive data types.
 It is well explained in Section 3.2 in the paper, but the idea is
 to generalise this pattern:

```
 Fix :: (∗ -> ∗) -> ∗
 Fix2 :: (∗ -> ∗ -> ∗) -> (∗ -> ∗ -> ∗) -> ∗
```

to

```
 Fixn :: ((∗ ->)^n * ->)^n ∗
 ≈
 Fixn :: (*^n -> *)^n -> *
```

To restrict how many types it does a fixed point over, they use type constructors
 instead of *^n. They give an example of an AST data type, mutually recursive over
 three types in the paper. I offer you perhaps the simplest example instead. Let
 us HFix this data type:

```
data Even = Zero | ESucc Odd deriving (Show,Eq)
data Odd  = OSucc Even       deriving (Show,Eq)
```

Let us introduce the family specific GADT for this datatype as is done in section 4.1

```
data EO :: * -> * where
  E :: EO Even
  O :: EO Odd
```

`EO Even` will mean that we are carrying around an even number.
 We need El instances for this to work, which says which specific constructor
 we are refering to when writing `EO Even` and `EO Odd` respectively.

```
instance El EO Even where proof = E
instance El EO Odd  where proof = O
```

These are used as constraints for the [`HFunctor` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multirec/0.7.1/doc/html/Generics-MultiRec-HFunctor.html#t%3aHFunctor)
 for [I](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multirec/0.7.1/doc/html/Generics-MultiRec-Base.html#t%3aI).

Let us now define the pattern functor for the even and odd data type.
 We use the combinators from the library. The [`:>:`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multirec/0.7.1/doc/html/Generics-MultiRec-Base.html#t%3a%3a-62-%3a) type constructor tags
 a value with its type index:

```
type PFEO = U      :>: Even   -- ≈ Zero  :: ()      -> EO Even
        :+: I Odd  :>: Even   -- ≈ ESucc :: EO Odd  -> EO Even
        :+: I Even :>: Odd    -- ≈ OSucc :: EO Even -> EO Odd
```

Now we can use `HFix` to tie the knot around this pattern functor:

```
type Even' = HFix PFEO Even
type Odd'  = HFix PFEO Odd
```

These are now isomorphic to EO Even and EO Odd, and we can use the
 [`hfrom` and `hto` functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multirec/0.7.1/doc/html/Generics-MultiRec-HFix.html)
 if we make it an instance of `Fam`:

```
type instance PF EO = PFEO

instance Fam EO where
  from E Zero      = L    (Tag U)
  from E (ESucc o) = R (L (Tag (I (I0 o))))
  from O (OSucc e) = R (R (Tag (I (I0 e))))
  to   E (L    (Tag U))           = Zero
  to   E (R (L (Tag (I (I0 o))))) = ESucc o
  to   O (R (R (Tag (I (I0 e))))) = OSucc e
```

A simple little test:

```
test :: Even'
test = hfrom E (ESucc (OSucc Zero))

test' :: Even
test' = hto E test

*HFix> test'
ESucc (OSucc Zero)
```

Another silly test with an Algebra turning `Even` and `Odd`s to their `Int` value:

```
newtype Const a b = Const { unConst :: a }

valueAlg :: Algebra EO (Const Int)
valueAlg _ = tag (\U             -> Const 0)
           & tag (\(I (Const x)) -> Const (succ x))
           & tag (\(I (Const x)) -> Const (succ x))

value :: Even -> Int
value = unConst . fold valueAlg E
```

Comment: Thank you, reading this has helped, but I'm still a little confused. Would you mind going into more detail on `:>:`, it still looks quite opaque to me.

Comment: Yes it is quite an involving library. I added a small comment about it, don't have any more time right now. Cheers!

Comment: It taken a little while, but having read and reread this, the API docs and the paper, it's finally starting to make sense. Thanks a lot, you've helped a lot.